# How to use data from loop in matplotlib graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have a loop (shown below)

Where after running it, it prints (t,d) up until d=0 again. How would I go about displaying this all in a graph in matplotlib? I'd rather not put each data point in one by one for all x and y values and I was wondering if there's a way to run the loop and display it in a graph.

```
t = 0
d = 0
v = 0
m = .1
g = -9.8
Ftr = 8
dt = .1
Cd=.5
cA=.1
r=.03
b=Cd*cA*.5*r
while d>=0:
    print (t,d)
    t=t+dt
    Ff=-b*v
    if t>3:
        Ftr=0
    Fw=m*g
    Fn=Ftr+Fw+Ff
    a=Fn/m
    dv=a*dt
    v=dv+v
    Dy=v*dt
    d=d+Dy
```

Comment: you don't want to keep the record of t and d in separate lists?

Answer (score 0):

While it is not clear why you don't want to store the results in a list, here is how you can plot the values one at a time

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

# Your remaining code up to while loop

while d>=0:
    # Rest of the code
    plt.plot(t, d, 'bo', ms=4) # Way 1 to plot
    # plt.scatter(t, d, color='b') # Way 2 to plot
plt.show()
```

[image]